# Custom order array in PHP

Tags: php

I got this array:

```
$array = array('E1211','E2172','E2181','E233','E241','E286');
```

And I need to order first by first number-letter, i.e. `E1, E2, E3, E4`... followed by ordered numbers from lowest to highest.

**Desired order would be**: `E1211, E233, E241, E286, E2172, E2181`

If i do `sort($array);` the order will will be: `"E1211", "E2172", "E2181", "E233", "E241" "E286"`.

If i do `natsort($array);` it will order by numbers from lowest to higest: `"E233", "E241", "E286", "E1211", "E2172", "E2181"`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232400/discussion-on-question-by-karles1-custom-order-array-in-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `usort()` with a custom comparison function to split the strings and compare the portions.

```
<?php

$array = array('E1211','E2172','E2181','E233','E241','E286');

usort($array, function($a, $b){
    $pfxA = substr($a,0,2);  // Get the first two characters of each string
    $pfxB = substr($b,0,2);
    if ( $pfxA !== $pfxB) {return $pfxA<=>$pfxB;}  // If they're not equal, return the spaceship comparison
    
    return (int)substr($a,2)<=>(int)substr($b,2);  // Prefixes are equal. Convert the rest to integers and return the spaceship comparison.
});


var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "E1211"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "E233"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "E241"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "E286"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "E2172"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "E2181"
}
```

See https://3v4l.org/5qts5

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you want to do is mixing sorting with your own pattern with `natsort()`. I doubt if it can be accomplished by some oneliner, however it can be done with simple iteration in separate steps, that code does what I think you want (input data modified for better readibility).

```php
<?php

$array = ['E3123', 'E1211', 'E2181', 'E241', 'E286', 'E2172', 'E233'];
$newArray = [];
$finalArray=[];

// Put it into associative array with required keys (two first chars)
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $key = substr($item, 0, 2);
    $newArray[$key][] = $item;
}

// sort new array by key (two first chars)
ksort($newArray);

// sort each subarray in natural order and put it to final array 
foreach ($newArray as $key => $newItem) {
    natsort($newArray[$key]);
    $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray, $newArray[$key]);
}

// just check
var_dump($finalArray);
```

Result:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'E1211' (length=5)
  1 => string 'E233' (length=4)
  2 => string 'E241' (length=4)
  3 => string 'E286' (length=4)
  4 => string 'E2172' (length=5)
  5 => string 'E2181' (length=5)
  6 => string 'E3123' (length=5)
```